# how to use "android-misc-widgets" in my project

Tags: android, open-source, widget, panel

I am creating a project, in which i want to use [this open source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/) in my project. I downloaded the files and ran that project which worked without any problem, but when i created a new separate project and try to use the widgets from that open source code, i am facing some errors like "`com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup" , "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`" .

Pls can anyone tell me how do i integrate the open source code in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configured it finally about how to use it.. made one library project and referred it in my original project. DONE

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **`com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView`** is not something that you can cast into a **`ViewGroup`** and use in your new project.

Check the definition for MockView in the open source code and then check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) before casting it in your own project.